# Map! procedure in Racket

Tags: racket

The map! procedure should modify the existing list to have the values of the operator applied to the original values.

For example:

```
(define a '(1 2 3 4 5))
(define double (lambda (x) (* x 2)))

(map! double a)
```

returns

```
done
```

Then when a is evaluated, a should return

```
(2 4 6 8 10)
```

**map!** procedure must do that work.

```
(define (map! operator given-list)
   (if (null? given-list) 'done
       (<the procedure that does the modification>)))
```

My guess1:

```
(map (lambda (x) (set! x (operator x))) given-list)

(map! double a)
```

returns:

```
'(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

My guess2:

```
(cons (operator (car given-list)) (map! double (cdr given-list)))

(map! double a)
```

returns:

```
'(2 4 6 8 10 . done)
```

My guess3:

```
(set! given-list (map operator given-list))

(map! double a)
```

returns:

```
'(2 4 6 8 10)
```

My guess4:

```
(let ((element (car given-list)))
      (set! element (operator given-list) (map! operator (cdr given-list)))

(map! double a)
```

returns:

```
'done
```

but, when **"a"** is evaluated, it still says:

```
'(1 2 3 4 5)
```

What do I have to do for this?????

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `set!` for this. You need to use `set-car!` on the cons cell you're changing. Here's how you might write it:

```
(define (map! f lst)
  (let loop ((rest lst))
    (unless (null? rest)
      (set-car! rest (f (car rest)))
      (loop (cdr rest)))))
```

If you have [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html), it's even easier (if we ignore for a moment that SRFI 1 already defines `map!` ;-)):

```
(define (map! f lst)
  (pair-for-each (lambda (pair)
                   (set-car! pair (f (car pair))))
                 lst))
```

Comment: I just noticed that your question is about Racket, not Scheme in general. Racket has immutable pairs by default, which means that you _cannot_ update a list in-place. Some Racket languages might let you use `set-car!`, but most won't.

Comment: I need to include the r5rs library to use the mutation concept. When I include that and I evaluate 'a' for the first time, it shows '(mcons 1 (mcons 2 (mcons....))) instead of '(1 2 3 4 5). Also, when I evaluate (map! op lst), it must say "done". I want to incorporate the 'done' output when list is null case.

Comment: What is the difference between `pair-for-each` and `maplist`? (Lisps first higher order function)

Comment: @Sylwester It's actually more similar to `mapl`, but returns an unspecified value.